# WebView seems to be leaking according to instruments. GeneralBlock-56

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

Instruments is reporting a lot of leaks like :

```
GeneralBlock-56
GeneralBlock-8192
GeneralBlock-2048
GeneralBlock-24
GeneralBlock-32
GeneralBlock-8
GeneralBlock-16
```

This all happens when I open a class that just displays a UIWebView.

Here is the guts of the code from the class:

```
    appDelegate = (DemoSAPAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
aWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[aWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[aWebView setOpaque:NO];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
[[[aWebView subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:YES]; 
[self.view addSubview:aWebView];
[aWebView release];
```

Am I doing something wrong here? The WebView is released there at the end.

Do I need to use something like an autoreleasepool?

Quite confused to see my app hemorrhage memory over this.

Comment: when does the leak occur? When the view displays or when it is removed?

Comment: Happens on display and on removal. Its related to the html page the UIWebView is displaying containing Javascript. UIWebView libs leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that on an actual device? Or the simulator? The frameworks the simulator uses leaks in many places; they are not as finely tuned as the device binaries. Always test on an actual device; the simulator, is after all, just a simulation.

Comment: It was on the device. Searching the web i found some mentions of the web-libraries that are implemented on the device leaking when the webpages that a UIWebView is showing contains JavaScript. So nothing (as far as i know) that we as developers can do to prevent this.